# Сравнение массивов. Удаление дубликатов

Tags: python

Есть два массива. Нужно 1 сравнить со 2 и в 1 удалить все значения которые были найдены в массиве 2. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: С чем именно у вас возникли проблемы? Приведите ваш вариант решения пускай он даже и неправильный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 4]    

print([x for x in a if x not in set(b)]) # [2, 3]

# либо
print(list(filter(lambda x: x not in set(b), a))) # [2, 3]

# либо если не важен порядок елементов  
print(list(set(a) - set(b)))
```