# Разница между двумя массивами

Tags: python

Есть 2 массива

```
a = ['dd','qq','aa']
b = ['qq']
```

как сравнить их и получить не уникальные значения?
к примеру `c = ['dd', 'aa']`

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1172060/178576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**способ 1:**

```
a = ['dd','qq','aa']
b = ['qq', 'xx']

res = [obj for obj in a if obj not in b] + [obj for obj in b if obj not in a]

print(res)
```

**способ 2:**

```
res = list(set(a).difference(b)) + list(set(b).difference(a))
```

**способ 3:**

```
res = list(set(a + b).difference(set(a).intersection(b)))
```

**способ 4:**

```
res = list(set(a) ^ set(b))
```

Comment: Последний метод (он же `symmetric_difference`) - самый простой и правильный )

Answer (score 0):

Похожий вариант:

```
list(set(a) - set(b))
```